# jQuery unique not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, unique

I've used $.unique before, but this timne, I can't get it to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/tNXZt/

I get an array of objects, but it does not seem to do anything with them. I hope you can help me here.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this causes the error but you have duplicate IDs in your example.

Comment: It's only for testing and one of them should be removed by the unique function.

Comment: Yes, but you have to think of the fact that other people might not take care of cases like that as they are not valid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

$.unique removes duplicates of a node, but there are not duplicate nodes inside the array, there are 3 different nodes. 2 nodes are not unique when they consist of the same markup, they must be the **same** DOMNode

for example here you would have duplicates:

```
[$(".test").get(0),
 $(".test").get(0)]
```

Comment: Exactly
The reason http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ works
is because the same instances are added to an array not because of the markup being the same

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the explanation. "Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed" - jQuery.com. If I have 2 elements with the same id's, I think these are dublicates. Maybe I'm wrong. Did you look at this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/

Comment: You're wrong, it doesn't matter what ID the nodes have, they must be the same node. the comparision of nodeA===nodeB must return true, what only will happen on the same nodes.

Comment: but we use .get() to put all objects into an array, so does not make sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense how you put it into the array, the only thing that matters is what will be inside the array, and there are no duplicates.